# Maxima: Returning function from function and evaluating it aftewards

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, maxima, computer-algebra-systems

I want to create a function in `Maxima` similar to [ConstantArray](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ConstantArray.html) in `Mathematica`. So I tried putting a wrapper around `make-array` but `make_array(fixnum,2,3,4)` takes last arguments as a sequence of parameters rather than a list while if one calls `ConstantArray(a,b,c,d..)` with variable number of arguments than I cannot pass it to make-array without putting it all as list.

To get around the problem of extracting elements from list passed as parameter and putting in make-array function, I tried,

```
    constantarray((l)):=block([eq:'make_array(fixnum)],
                        map(lambda([x],eq:endcons(x,eq)),l),eq);
```

which on calling

```
constantarray([1,2,3,5,3]);
```

returns

> make_array(fixnum,1,2,3,5,3)

This function executes well if I copy this output, paste it on console and run it as it returns me the `Lisp array [1,2,3,5,3]`.

I have tried evaluating it using `''%` & `ev(constantarray(1,2,3,5,3),nouns)` etc but its just not working. I want to know if someone knows how to force this evaluation or I am doing something not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
constant_array ([L]) := block ([x : first (L), d : rest (L)],
    apply (make_array, cons ('any, d)),
    fillarray (%%, [x]));
```

A function definition `foo([L]) := ...` means that the function takes a variable number of arguments, and `L` is the list of arguments actually supplied. `apply (make_array, cons ('any, d))` is like calling `make_array('any, d[1], d[2], d[3], ...)`. Also, in a block, `%%` is the value of the previous expression.

Example:

```
constant_array (1234, 4, 3, 2);
  => {Lisp Array: 
    #3A(((1234 1234) (1234 1234) (1234 1234))
        ((1234 1234) (1234 1234) (1234 1234))
        ((1234 1234) (1234 1234) (1234 1234))
        ((1234 1234) (1234 1234) (1234 1234)))}
```

Comment: this seems to work just fine and I am thankful for this suggestion as well. But I was just wondering too if the way I was doing it is feasible.

Comment: @Rorschach in the result that you got, you can write `ev(%, nouns)` to evaluate the `make_array` noun expression.